# Angular2: recommended way to connect ngrx stream directly into Form?

Tags: angular, ngrx

Angular2: recommended way to connect ngrx stream directly into Form?

I checked the web and the best I can find is this but looking for best practices to connect ngrx stream into a reactive form. this is what I found so far:

```
@Component({
  template: `<dumb-component [form]="form" [data]="data$ | async"></dumb-component>`
})
class SmartComponent {
  public data$ = this._store.let(someSelector$());

  public form = new FormGroup({
   foo: new FormControl(''),
   bar: new FormControl('')
  });

  constructor(private _store: Store<IState>) {}
}

@Component({
  template: `
    <form [formGroup]="form">
      <input type="text" formControlName="foo" />
      <input type="text" formControlName="bar" />
    </form>
  `
})
class DumbComponent {
  @Input()
  public form: FormGroup;

  @Input()
  set data(v) {
    if (v) {
      this.form.patchValue(v);
    }
  };
}
```

regards,

Sean

Comment: Please edit into your question an example of whatever practice is recommended in the linked issue.

Comment: I wouldn't pass a FormGroup as a parameter to the DumbComponent. I would be passing an object and creating the formGroup from it.

Comment: Using smart and dumb components is the way to go, but passing the `FormGroup` into the dumb component seems a little code-smelly, to me.

Answer (score 0):

To go with what those in the comments already said, I wouldn't pass the FormGroup.

Something more like this should work:

```
@Component({
    template: `<dumb-component (mySubmit)="handleSubmit($event)" [data]="data$ | async"></dumb-component>`
})
class SmartComponent {
    public data$ = this._store.let(someSelector$());

    constructor(private _store: Store<IState>) {}

    handleSubmit(obj: any) {
       this._store.dispatch(...);
    }
}

@Component({
    template: `
        <form [formGroup]="form">
            <input type="text" formControlName="foo" />
            <input type="text" formControlName="bar" />
        </form>
    `
})
class DumbComponent {
    public form: FormGroup;
    @Output mySubmit = new EventEmitter<any>();

    constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
        form = this.fb.group({
            foo: '',
            bar: ''
        });
    }

    onSubmit() {
        if (this.form.valid) {
            this.mySubmit.emit(this.form.value);
        }
    }

    @Input()
    set data(v) {
        if (v) {
            this.form.patchValue(v);
        }
    };
}
```

The smart component will handle pulling from the store and putting it back in the store.